# Android: detect when the app is killed

Tags: android, kill

Is there a way to detect when the Android system kills my application?

Comment: What about parsing the logs to see if an application has been killed?

Answer (score 4):

After investigation I want to say that there is no way to detect if your application is killed  inside application even if we try to use shutdown hooks.

Comment: True. Shutdown hooks will not work on Android. From Android's Runtime class docs - `Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that your code is run. Instead, you should use the most appropriate lifecycle notification (Activity.onPause, say).`